# Unwrap faces without effecting other faces?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I s it possible to unwrap certain faces without effecting other ones? I tried to pin them but pinning does not really help here.

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to select only the faces that you want to unwrap again in the viewport (right side)?

Comment: Pinned vertices should not move. I've just tested it with the default cube. Maybe you have duplicated verts or flipped normals so that the UV islands get twisted (screenshot 2, the arrow)?

Comment: No, don't have duplicated verts and normals are not flipped. I have this issues most of the time. Pinning ist not really reliable. And yes I've tried with selecting.

Answer (score 1):

Until you get a proper answer, I can at least offer a workaround in the meantime (or this might be the actual way to do it). When you hit Unwrap, I know that **hidden faces are not affected**. I've even tested it myself with a regular UV Sphere. Here is one that has not been touched:
[image]

Let's say I want to preserve the UVs of the left side of the sphere, and I want them to stay exactly where they are on the UV map (selected for clarity):
[image]

I'll hide the left side, leaving only the right:
[image]

When I select > all then unwrap, I get this unwrapped dome, and I'll move the unwrapped UV island off to the side for now:
[image]
[image]

When I unhide the left part of the sphere, and check its UV, the left side of the sphere's UVs has not been moved at all despite the fact that I used unwrap on the right side of the sphere:
[image]